# Why am I getting a value error for trying to bubble plot categories?

Tags: python, plotly, graphing

I am trying to follow and learn how to use plotly, and am having problems with this code.  I can't get it to graph the different colors, it graphs just one color without the legends.  But I didn't receive errors in the previous lines, previously until the figure portion of the code? What am I doing wrong?

Here is a link to the dataset, it's named `NewOrders.xlsx`

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eEL3dpCk_mfSsvEhME04-qJkWjrpi8Ib

```
trace0=[go.Scatter(
    x=orders['Sales'][orders['Order Priority']=='High'],
    y=orders['Profit'][orders['Order Priority']=='High'],
    name='High',
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=100*orders['Discount'][orders['Order 
    Priority']=='High']))]

trace1=[go.Scatter(
    x=orders['Sales'][orders['Order Priority']=='Medium'],
    y=orders['Profit'][orders['Order Priority']=='Medium'],
    name='Medium',
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=100*orders['Discount'][orders['Order ` ` 
    Priority']=='Medium']))]

trace2=[go.Scatter(
    x=orders['Sales'][orders['Order Priority']=='Low'],
    y=orders['Profit'][orders['Order Priority']=='Low'],
    name='Low',
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=100*orders['Discount'][orders['Order 
    Priority']=='Low']))]

data=[trace0, trace1, trace2]

layout=go.Layout(
    title='Sales vs Profit',
    xaxis=dict(title='Sales'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Profit'),
    hovermode='closest')

figure=go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
```

## Error : ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

in 
----> 1 figure=go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use `plotly.express`

## `plotly.express`

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_excel("NewOrders.xlsx")
ddf = df[df["Order Priority"].isin(["High", "Medium", "Low"])]

# you can eventually create a column
# ddf["Discount_100"] = ddf["Discount] * 100

fig = px.scatter(ddf,
                 x="Sales",
                 y="Profit",
                 color="Order Priority",
                 size="Discount")

fig.update_layout(title='Sales vs Profit',
                  title_x=0.5,
                  hovermode="closest")
fig.show()
```

[image]

## `plotly.graph_objs`

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.read_excel("NewOrders.xlsx")

traces = []
colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]
for i, priority in enumerate(["High", "Medium", "Low"]):
    ddf = df[df["Order Priority"]==priority]
    traces.append(
        go.Scatter(x=ddf["Sales"],
                   y=ddf["Profit"],
                   name=priority,
                   mode='markers',
                   marker=dict(size=100*ddf["Discount"],
                               color=colors[i])
                   ))
layout = dict(title='Sales vs Profit',
              title_x=0.5,
              hovermode="closest",
              xaxis=dict(title='Sales'),
              yaxis=dict(title='Profit'))

fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

[image]